# Why RemoteViews doesn't respect TextView sized in pixel which set through setFloat

Tags: android

I have 2 `TextView`s in my home widget. For the 3rd column, I specific the size in pixel, through XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:width="0dp"        
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="24px"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />
```

For the 2nd (middle) column, I specific the size in pixel too, through Java code.

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    ...
    remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.text_view_1, "setTextSize", 24);
```

I expect the 2nd column and 3rd column will be in same size, as both are using 24 pixel.

But, if looking at screenshot, that is not the case! Anything I had done wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `setFloat()` applied to `"setTextSize"` always uses `sp`. Here is the method which gets called at the end.

```
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
}
```

Try to use the method below to set test size in `px`.

```
remoteViews.setTextViewTextSize(R.id.text_view_1, 
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 24);
```

**Update:** If you need to support Gingerbread you should use `setFloat()`. Knowing that it expects `sp` I would try to provide a smaller value in there, which, after scaling, would correspond to desired `px` size. I believe this would be the formula. I wasn't able to test it, but it might work.

```
float size = 24 / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
remoteViews.setFloat(R.id.text_view_1, "setTextSize", size);
```

Comment: Oh, do you have any documentation on that? As if we refer to `TextView`'s `setTextSize` documentation directly, the expected unit is in `pixel`.

Comment: Check out source code of TextView and RemoteViews. It's all there. I updated the answer.

Comment: I can't use `setTextViewTextSize` as we need to support Gingerbread. Interesting. From the source code, I can clearly see the used unit is sp. However, from documentation, it states `The scaled pixel size.`. I thought sp stands for `Scale-independent Pixels`, which is different from `The scaled pixel size.`? Sorry, I'm confusing.

Comment: sp is scaled pixel independent value. It's like dp but can be scaled up or down depending on font size preference user can change. I update the answer with a solution which might work in your case.